# How do you get the user data from a HTML input (text) created using createElement()?

Tags: javascript

**My Problem**

I would like some help understanding how to access the value inside input1 and input2, store them in a variable so I can later use them with a function that will calculate the two values and display it in the result div.

```
const input1 = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(input1);

const input2 = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(input2);

const result = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an idea can be to use EventListener on the created input to manipulate the data

```js
const input1 = document.createElement("INPUT");
document.body.appendChild(input1);
input1.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  console.log(target.value);
});
```

you can also add a selector (id or class) to the created element and recover it by this selector

```js
const input1 = document.createElement("INPUT");
document.body.appendChild(input1);
input1.id = 'test';

function showData() {
  var input = document.getElementById('test');
  console.log(input.value);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showData()">show data</button>
```

with your sample it can look like

```js
const input1 = document.createElement("INPUT");
input1.id = 'input1';
document.body.appendChild(input1);

const input2 = document.createElement("INPUT");
input2.id = 'input2';
document.body.appendChild(input2);

const result = document.createElement("DIV");
result.id = 'result';
document.body.appendChild(result);


function showResult() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
  var input2 = document.getElementById('input2');
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  if (input1 && input2 && result) {
    result.innerText = input1.value * input2.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showResult()">show result</button>
```

if you have to dynamically create div and showresult you can also create the button and manipulate the onclick event

```js
var numberOfRow = 0;

function copyResultInNextInput(nextNumber, result) {
  var next = document.getElementById('input1_' + (nextNumber));
  if (next) {
    next.value = result.innerText;
  }
}

function createNewRow(haveSeveralButtons) {
  numberOfRow++;
  const nextNumber = numberOfRow + 1;
  const input1 = document.createElement("INPUT");
  input1.id = 'input1_' + numberOfRow;
  document.body.appendChild(input1);

  const input2 = document.createElement("INPUT");
  input2.id = 'input2_' + numberOfRow;
  document.body.appendChild(input2);

  const result = document.createElement("DIV");
  result.id = 'result_' + numberOfRow;
  document.body.appendChild(result);

  const button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  button.innerText = 'show result';
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    result.innerText = input1.value * input2.value;
    if (!haveSeveralButtons) {
      copyResultInNextInput(nextNumber, result);
    }
  });
  document.body.appendChild(button);

  if (haveSeveralButtons) {
    const button2 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    button2.innerText = 'copy result in next input1';
    button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
      copyResultInNextInput(nextNumber, result);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(button2);
  }

  const hr = document.createElement("HR");
  document.body.appendChild(hr);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createNewRow(false)">create New Row with one button</button>
<button onclick="createNewRow(true)">create New Row with two buttons</button>
<hr/>
```

Comment: Thanks for everything you have shared.  I have one more question. Let say I wanted to use the result from a row and place it in the row below it as input2.

Comment: in that case you will have to identify each created element, create a function that recover wanted element (with getElementByID for sample) I edit my reply to show you this case

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the Id work, but it only works for that one row.  I need to repeat that process (equation) independanly on each new row that's created.

Comment: i edit my previous reply to be able to generate dynamic row and have the result with a button

Comment: please add comment to the reply if you want more elements and not a reply to the topic

Comment: firstly, thanks again.  How do you mark your replies as solved and how would you use your code if you removed the show and copy the result in the next input1 button as my calculator only has one button called add row.  I am struggling to add multiple event listeners to one button using your code. many thanks. Sorry, i am a novice and have much to learn.

Comment: to mark reply there is a little tick next reply score at the left of reply. in your case you can have several listener but you can also have two functions called in one listener. I edit my reply to have only one button